Converting CatBoost 'approx' Scores to Probabilities for PMML Deployment
I'm deploying a CatBoost model for default prediction and need to output the probability of default using PMML. According to the CatBoost documentation, when using CatBoostClassifier to save a PMML file, it only outputs true or false. I've tried to manually convert the output to probabilities by examining the 'approx' values in the PMML file, but I'm encountering some issues.
When I open the PMML file with Notepad++, I can find the 'approx' output of the last tree, but the scores are in the range of -1 to 1, which doesn't seem to be convertible to a probability distribution through the sigmoid function. I've tried applying a sigmoid transformation to the scores of the last tree, but the resulting probabilities are all around 0.5, which doesn't seem correct.
Does anyone have experience with this and can provide guidance on how to correctly convert the 'approx' scores to probabilities? Is the 'approx' value the sum of all trees' outputs? If so, how should I interpret and convert these values to get meaningful probabilities?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.
Maybe using the following method?
// dependency：
// <dependency>
//   <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
//   <artifactId>jpmml-catboost</artifactId>
//   <version>1.7.0</version> <!-- or latest version -->
// </dependency>
import ai.h2o.jpmml.catboost.ConverterUtil;
import org.dmg.pmml.PMML;
// ... load your CatBoost model ...
Model model = CatBoostModel.load("my_catboost_model.cbm");
// convert to PMML
PMML pmml = ConverterUtil.convert(model);
// save PMML file
JAXBUtil.marshalPMML(pmml, new File("my_catboost_model.pmml"));

Thank you!
How to convert cbm format to pmml path in java environment
